# How to connect Stanford Core Server from dotnet

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to use Stanford NLP for.NET. I am very new to this.

How can I connect Stanford core NLP server from c# program

My NLP server runs on localhost:9000

Answer (score 0):

You can connect via the .NET HTTPClient or other equivalent .NET call to a web endpoint. You need to set up your NLP endpoint, properties for the NLP server, and the text content you want it to parse. There is additional information on the [Stanford NLP Server page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html), as well as information on what properties can be set depending on what NLP pipeline you want to run.

The following code is from a **.NET Core console application** using the following call to return Named Entity Recognition, Dependency Parser and OpenIE results.

FYI I've had some occasions where my NLP endpoint didn't work when waking a laptop from sleep mode (Docker for Windows pre 17.12 on Win10). Resetting Docker did the trick for me... if you can't browse to your http://localhost:9000 website, then the endpoint definitely won't work either!

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net.Http;

    // String to process
    string s = "This is the sentence to provide to NLP."

    // Set up the endpoint
    string nlpBaseAddress = "http://localhost:9000"

    // Create the query string params for NLPCore
    string jsonOptions = "{\"annotators\": \"ner, depparse, openie\", \"outputformat\": \"json\"}";
    Dictionary qstringProperties = new Dictionary();
    qstringProperties.Add("properties", jsonOptions);
    string qString = ToQueryString(qstringProperties);

    // Add the query string to the base address
    string urlPlusQuery = nlpBaseAddress + qString;

    // Create the content to submit
    var content = new StringContent(s);
    content.Headers.Clear();
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Submit for processing
    var client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response;
    Task tResponse = client.PostAsync(urlPlusQuery, content);
    tResponse.Wait();
    response = tResponse.Result;

    // Check the response
    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
       // Do something better than throwing an app exception here!
       throw new ApplicationException("Subject-Object tuple extraction returned an unexpected response from the subject-object service");
    }

    Task rString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    rString.Wait();
    string jsonResult = rString.Result;
```

Utility function used within this call to generate a QueryString:

```
        

    private string ToQueryString(Dictionary nvc)
            {
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("?");

                bool first = true;

                foreach (KeyValuePair key in nvc)
                {
                    // CHeck if this is the first value
                    if (!first)
                    {
                        sb.Append("&");
                    }

                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(key.Key), Uri.EscapeDataString(key.Value));

                    first = false;
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }
```